AWS directory service multi region replication issue
I am using terraform for the creation of directory service, us-gov-cloud region I specified both regions correctly as mentioned in terraform registry.
the error i am facing:

creating Directory Service Region (d-c2670****, us-gov-west-1): UnsupportedOperationException: The region you specified is the same region where the AWS Managed Microsoft AD directory was created. Specify a different region and try again.: RequestId: 63e0805e-f38c-498d-b943-dd62ace****

AD should be replicated to another region as well

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure you read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

I have given region correctly , the issue is I need to pass the actual Directory Id created on east on previous phase or output as data to pass id directly and I can able to create cross region relocation. ☺️

This would better be a comment on the original question.
